# How can i Enable android.wallpaper.tap option in android Livewallpaper?

Tags: android, live-wallpaper

I create a sample Live wallpaper application, My requirement is, the Live-wallpaper have a water look (Water Surface). when i touch any surface on the screen the water must repel. I go through regarding this in developer site, finally i got the key word `android.wallpaper.tap` is used for this purpose, now i doesn't know how to use this. Also i need this functionality enabled live wallpaper tutorials are code snippet if any one know this, kindly post it. Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a code snippet borrowed from [libgdx live wallpaper backend](http://code.google.com/p/libgdx-backend-android-livewallpaper/) (WallpaperService.Engine);

```
@Override
public Bundle onCommand(final String pAction, final int pX,
           final int pY, final int pZ, final Bundle pExtras,
           final boolean pResultRequested) {

    if (pAction.equals(WallpaperManager.COMMAND_TAP)) {
        ((AndroidInputLW) app.getInput()).onTap(pX, pY);
    } else if (pAction.equals(WallpaperManager.COMMAND_DROP)) {
        ((AndroidInputLW) app.getInput()).onDrop(pX, pY);
    }

    return super.onCommand(pAction, pX, pY, pZ, pExtras,
                           pResultRequested);
}
```

I've never tried this myself but would expect utilizing `Engine.onCommand` method should be rather straightforward as long as you keep receiving these events.